# Null value after passing parameter between activities

Tags: android

I need to pass two Hashmaps between two activities. I've been trying to pass it with intent but when new activity is started one my HashMap is null, while the second one is passed correctly. Do you know why does it happen?

This is how I start new activity with HashMap:

```
routeIntent.putExtra("routeMap", routeMap);
routeIntent.putExtra("stopsMap", stopsMap);
startActivity(routeIntent);
```

And how I received parameters in new activit:

```
HashMap<String, String> routeMap = (HashMap<String, String>) this.getIntent().getSerializableExtra("routeMap");

HashMap<String, String> stopsMap = (HashMap<String, String>) this.getIntent().getSerializableExtra("stopsMap");
```

And when I print value of stopsMap it's null. Are there any limits of size or number of parameters in sending parameters with intent?

Comment: are you sure when you are passing it does not contain null value?

Comment: Yeah. Sam is right. The only solution is that you are already passing a null HashMap. Can you please provide the code where you create and populate both maps?

Comment: Try to see values by debugging. shift+f9 to debug, also set some breakpoint.

Comment: What is the size of your HashMap? keep in mind that the maximum length of intent data is 1MB

Comment: Thank you all for help, I finally managed to solve it, the problem was in my code in calling wrong methods.